# How to exchange all options within select field with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have two select fields in a form - make and model. My goal is to change the options of field "model"  upon selecting another make. E.g. Select BMW, show all BMW models.

Therefore I am doing an ajax call to retrieve those values and then I want to build the other form.

The code for building the options:

```
obj = JSON.parse(json);
$.each(obj.item, function(key,valueObj){
    Object.keys(valueObj || {}).forEach(function(k) {
    $('#filter_model').append(
            $('<option></option>').val(k).html(valueObj[k])
    );
})
```

This works by appending new options. But of course as I keep on changing the make, it will just add new models to the select fields. I would either need to remove all existing ones or somehow rebuild the entire field. The later one would be my preference as I later want to only show the model field upon selecting the make.

How could this be acchieved?

Comment: Sounds like all you need is to call `$('#filter_model').empty()` before the loop that appends new options

Comment: Thank you! That fixed it with some additions: <code>$('#filter_model').empty();
$('#filter_model').append('<option value="" selected>Auswählen</option>');
$('#filter_model').selectmenu("refresh", true);</code>

Answer (score 1):

Appending within a loop isn't a good idea as it is an expensive operation to run. Instead, you could build a string of HTML within your loop and then set that as your content for `#filter_model` using the `.html()` method (thus only modifying the DOM once):

```
obj = JSON.parse(json);
var strHTML = "";
$.each(obj.item, function(key,valueObj) {
    Object.keys(valueObj || {}).forEach(function(k) {
      strHTML += '<option value="' + k +'">' + valueObj[k] +'</option>';
    });
});

$('#filter_model').html(strHTML);
```

Or, alternatively, as suggested by [@charlietfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175966/charlietfl), you could instead build an array of your jQuery objects and then use `.html()` on that array:

```
obj = JSON.parse(json);
var options = [];
$.each(obj.item, function(key,valueObj) {
    Object.keys(valueObj || {}).forEach(function(k) {
      options.push($('<option></option>').val(k).html(valueObj[k]));
    });
});

$('#filter_model').html(options);
```

Comment: you are concatenating jQuery objects to string inside the loop

Comment: @charlietfl thanks, I believe I've fixed the issue now

Comment: Can also pass array of objects to `html()`

Comment: @charlietfl oh, I wasn't aware you could do that. Thanks for informing me :)

Comment: @NickParsons nice answer, I didn't realized until now that the `.html` is also clearing *data* and *event handlers* like `.empty` does! I believe this need to be emphasized in Your answer.